# How can I decide scrum product backlog and task for this stuation?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, scrum, user-stories, azure-devops

I am planning a Project with scrum. This Project including a web Project and proparing some autocad projects(10 or more 3D) to publish from web. Two developers will develop web Project and three employee will prepare autocad files. 
How can I write user story for autocad developers? 
I am using Visual Studio TFS online.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  How to enter User Stories into TFS?  Or how to figure out what the user stories should be?  If it's the latter, show us an example of what you're thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you don't write User Stories *for* any particular type of developer.  User Stories should be in terms of business/customer value.  A user story may require some code and/or autocad development to implement, but User Stories should be in business/customer language and focused on customer value/goals - not structured around technical competencies.